# Unexpected behaviour in React Js Routing between Pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-component, react-router-component

Here i'm implementing a simple routing program to route between pages in react js. I'm experiencing unexpected behaviour on run time.

Here is my **App.js** Code

```js
import LoginPage from './LoginPage'
import React from 'react';
import Home from './Home'
import About from './About'
import ContactUs from './ContactUs'
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter,Switch,Route,Link } from 'react-router-dom'
  
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <BrowserRouter>
    
         <div>
           <ul>
          <li>     <Link to="/Home">Home</Link>               </li> 
          <li>     <Link to="/About">About</Link>          </li>   
          <li>     <Link to="/ContactUs">ContactUs</Link>        </li> 
               </ul>
          
             {/**/} <Switch> 

                <Route  path="/Home"></Route>
                 <Home/>
                 <Route path="/About"></Route>
                 <About/>
                 <Route path="/ContactUs"></Route>
                 <ContactUs/>


               </Switch>
               </div>
         </BrowserRouter>
         {/*<LoginPage/>*/} 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

- When I run the code first Home.js Page should visible. It is coming without any issue
  [Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzFH4.png)
- The issue here is when i click on **Home** Button again it displaying an empty page just with the routing switches. Here is the picture of the output[when clicking on home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p67oI.png)
- Code of **Home.js**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class Home extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="Home_pg">
          <h1>Home Page</h1>
          <p>Home page content</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  export default Home;
```

- ***The main problem which I'm facing is when i clicked either ContactUs or About in the main page its not displaying the contents on the respective pages***.
- It is displaying the same contents for the Home Page.
- Image when clicking About or Contact US[Image when clicking About or Contact US](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN9eO.png)
- Here is the code for **ContactUs.js** and **About.JS**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class About extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div >
          <h1>About Page</h1>
          <p> About content</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  export default About;
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

 - **ContactUs.js**

class ContactUs extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div >
          <h1>Contact Page</h1>
          <p> Contact content</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  export default ContactUs;
```

Here i'm not clear why it is happening . Is it any issue with my class components?.Any suggestions or solution regarding this will be more than helpful for me.

Comment: Make sure you have used `exact` prop for `Route`.

Comment: <Route  path="/Home" component={Home} />
<Route path="/About" component={About} />
<Route path="/ContactUs" component={ContactUs} /> just try these lines

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to put each component inside its relevant Route tag.
In addition I suggest to add two things:
- lazy loading for components.
- a Suspense tag with some loading indication (text or spinner).

import LoginPage from './LoginPage'
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter,Switch,Route,Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home= lazy(() => import('./Home'));
const About = lazy(() => import('./About'));
const ContactUs = lazy(() => import('./ContactUs'));
  
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <BrowserRouter>
         <div>
           <ul>
             <li><Link to="/Home">Home</Link></li> 
             <li><Link to="/About">About</Link></li>   
             <li><Link to="/ContactUs">ContactUs</Link></li> 
           </ul>
           <Suspense fallback={<div>loading..</div>}
              <Switch> 
                <Route  path="/Home"><Home/></Route>
                <Route path="/About"><About/></Route>
                <Route path="/ContactUs"><ContactUs/></Route>
              </Switch>
           </Suspense>
          </div>
         </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: </ul>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>loading..</div>}
               <Switch> 
                 ^
                <Route  path="/Home"><Home/></Route>
                 <Route path="/About"><About/></Route>
                   <Route path="/ContactUs"><ContactUs/></Route>                I'm getting errors for switch and route.

Comment: The code is running fine if i  remove this tag. <Suspense fallback={<div>loading..</div>}     Thanks for the help.

Comment: @VISHNUPRASAD That's because I forgot to import this.
In addition, I forgot to mention lazy loading.
See the edited answer above.